# How to fix SVG rotation for isometric grid pattern

Tags: svg, rotation, isometric, skew

I am trying to construct an isometric grid with SVG.
Following the suggestions of [this tutorial](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-isometric-illustrations-using-the-ssr-method--vector-1058), I have the following code:

```
 <svg viewBox="-5 -5 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect x="-3" y="-3" width="6" height="6" />
     <rect x="-3" y="-3" width="6" height="6" fill="red"
         transform="scale(1 .8602)" /> 
     <rect x="-3" y="-3" width="6" height="6" fill="yellow"
         transform="scale(1 .8602) skewX(-30)" /> 
     <rect x="-3" y="-3" width="6" height="6" fill="orange"
         transform="scale(1 .8602) skewX(-30) rotate(30)" />
     <circle cx="0" cy="0" r=".32" fill="navy"/>
</svg>
```

But instead of yielding this shape (as in the tutorial):
[image: From tutorial]

The final result is what's shown in orange in the:
[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/fmkatz/pen/ExxJzXL?&editable=true#anon-signup)

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformations in svg are applied back to front. Reversing the order of your transformations will do the trick...

`transform="rotate(30) skewX(-30) scale(1 .8602)"`

Comment: Yes. That does it; thanks.I have added a corrected version to the CodePen mentioned above.